# Move and replace each image in all subdirectories that are over a certain resolution

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a need to run a cron job every day to move all images that are over 1000px in width or height and then replace the moved image with a default image which lives in the same directory that is running this script.

```
/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/images/too_large.jpg //file used to replace old image
```

I have been able to filter all images using:

```
find -type f -regex "^.*\.\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\)$" -printf "%p, " -exec identify -format "%w, %h\n" {} \; | awk -F ',' '$2 > 1000 || $3 > 1000'
```

Which will output

```
./b1/Eldar_Guardian.png, 892, 1767
./b2/Farseer_with_Guardians1.png, 894, 1308
```

Which is displaying the files, but truth is without dropping `awk` I'm not sure how to actually move these images and then store the original file name over for the `cp` of the `too_large.jpg`

My goal was to use Bash for this, however maybe `Php` is also an option if anybody would prefer.

Another annoying requirement is that the original filetype needs to persist, which there is a relevant `too_large` file present too.

- Move images that are over either 1000px in height or in width, whichever matches.
- cp too_large[.jpg/.png/.jpg] to moved image location

Comment: What does the current output look like on a hit?

Comment: Ah yes, I have updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have details in place, how about something like this -

```
find -type f -regex "^.*\.\(png\|jpg\|jpeg\)$" -printf "%p, " -exec identify -format "%w, %h\n" {} \; |
  awk -F ',' '$2 > 1000 || $3 > 1000 {print $1}' |
  while read -r file
  do mv "$file" "some/other/place/$newName"
     cp /gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/images/too_large.jpg "$file"
  done
```

Your original `find` returns filenames and pixel counts vertically and horizontally.

```
./b1/Eldar_Guardian.png, 892, 1767
./b2/Farseer_with_Guardians1.png, 894, 1308
```

Your `awk` was already selecting for oversized files; I just added a step to only print the filename when it found one.

```
  awk -F ',' '$2 > 1000 || $3 > 1000 {print $1}' | # print of X or Y >1k
```

So the loop only has to read and process filenames.

Comment: How does the `file` in `while read -r file` know that these are files from the string when it includes `, 800 x 800` for example

Comment: Your `awk` was already selecting for files too big. The `while ` assumes the `awk` removes files that are ok.

Comment: Ah! Stupid me, sorry ye I missed the `print $1` oddly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with PHP this pseudo code should work with minor tweaks. You will want to make sure that you are in the correct directory (chdir) as the example assumes that the files you are checking are in the directory that the PHP is being run in.

```
$imagelist = glob('*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($imagelist as $image) {

    $image_info = getimagesize($image);
    if ($image_info[0] > 1000 OR
        $image_info[1] > 1000) {

        rename($image,'movebigfilelocation');
        copy('/gwart.co.uk/mediawiki/images/too_large.jpg',$image);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP and [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), you could also just downscale the images. Snippet:

```
$maxXres = 1000;

$mimg = new \Imagick($img['tmp_name']);
$xresolution = $mimg->getImageWidth();

if ($xresolution > $this->maxXres){
   $mimg->thumbnailImage($this->maxXres, 0);
}

$fn = "/where/ever/downscaled.jpg";
$mimg->writeImage($fn);
```

Then overwrite the original file wit $fn. The example only considers the x-axis, but how to check for the y-side is the same, just with getImageHeight instead.